# Why do Cordova plugins work even if they aren't added to config.xml?

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I ran `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` in order to gain access to the camera. However, when I check my config.xml file, there is no line that signifies I've added the camera plugin. Other plugins have a line such as `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>` within `config.xml`.

Why don't I need a `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera">` and where can I find the list of plugins that I've added? Is `cordova info` the only way?

If it helps, I am doing all of this in an Ionic 2 project. I don't think that makes a difference, but adding it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`, the plugin will be downloaded to your `plugins` folder. It is then available when you build your project.

You can see all the plugins that are available in your project by running `cordova plugins list`. The camera plugin should be there as well.

However, when want to set up your project on another computer (or delete your plugins folder), the camera plugin will not be installed again because it's not in the config.xml.

So when you permanently want to add a cordova plugin to your project, you need to add the --save parameter: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save`. This will save it to your config.xml

EDIT:

You can use the `cordova prepare` command to redownload the plugins:

`Cordova prepare:
Transforms config.xml metadata to platform-specific manifest files, copies icons & splashscreens, copies plugin files for specified platforms so that the project is ready to build with each native SDK.`

Comment: Didn't realize it behaved similarly to `npm`. That makes sense.